# regular expression to match given requirement

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as:

```
s = '((FILTER( "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"=''OPEN''))*
 (FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."OpportunityRevenue" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"=''OPEN'')/
 FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"=''OPEN''))*
 (FILTER ( "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory" = ''WON'') / 
 "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" ))/
 ((1.0 * "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."TotalSalesCycleOppty")  / 
 FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory" = ''WON''))'
```

It has reference to tables as `"SchemaName"."TableName"."ColumnName"`
I need to extract info for all tables with Schema as
`"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"
"SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"`

```
import re
pat = r'".*?\"\.".*?\"'             #See Note at the bottom of the answer
s = '((FILTER( "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"=''OPEN''))*
 (FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."OpportunityRevenue" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"=''OPEN'')/
 FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"=''OPEN''))*
 (FILTER ( "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory" = ''WON'') / 
 "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" ))/
 ((1.0 * "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."TotalSalesCycleOppty")  / 
 FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" 
 USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory" = ''WON''))'
match1 = re.findall(pat, s)
print(match1)
```

It gives output as:

```
['"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', 
'"#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', 
'"OpportunityStatusCategory"=OPEN))*(FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', 
'"OpportunityRevenue" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', 
'"OpportunityStatusCategory"=OPEN)/FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', 
'"#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', 
'"OpportunityStatusCategory"=OPEN))*(FILTER ("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', 
'"#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', 
'"OpportunityStatusCategory" = WON) / "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', 
'"#Opportunities" ))/((1.0 * "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', 
'"TotalSalesCycleOppty")  / FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', 
'"#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"']
```

Which is not correct, for example second value:

```
('"#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"')
```

My expression check is as starting with " then .*? for all characters till it reaches \" then dot then again " then .*? for all characters till it reaches \"

What am I missing?

Comment: Use a negated character class (like `[^"]*`) rather than a `.*?` (the first occurrence at least).

Comment: You need to pare down your question, the pattern is just too big to see all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression (amended as per Wiktor Stribizew's suggestion should work):  `"[^"]*?\"\."[^"]*\"`

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
import re

s = '''((FILTER( "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"='OPEN'))*(FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."OpportunityRevenue" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"='OPEN')/FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory"='OPEN'))*(FILTER ( "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory" = 'WON') / "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" ))/((1.0 * "SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."TotalSalesCycleOppty")  / FILTER("SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"."#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"."OpportunityStatusCategory" = 'WON'))'''

pat = r'"[^"]*?"\."[^"]*?"'             #See Note at the bottom of the answer

match1 = re.findall(pat, s)
print(match1)
```

Output:

```
['"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', '"SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', '"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', '"SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', '"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', '"SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', '"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', '"SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"', '"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', '"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', '"SalesVelocity"."OrderHeader"', '"SalesVelocity"."Opportunity_1"']
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand backtracking

- `".*?"` matches the shortest subsequence betwen next `"` and `"`
- `".*?"\.` matches the shortest subsequence betwen next `"` and `".`

so `".*?"\.` matches `"#Opportunities" USING "SalesVelocity".` because after `"\.` match fail it backtracks to `.*`

a negative lookahead is more expressive because it specifies exactly the unwanted tokens,

```
"(?:(?!").)*"\.".*?"
```

another fix can be to use an atomic group around ".*?"

```
"(?>.*?")\.".*?"
```

but in your case it's more eficient to use a negative character: `[^"]*`, because it avoids backtracking.